# iOS load YouTube video and not webpage

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I want to load a youtube video and not the webpage in a UIWebView - It could be a different control if available but I am not aware of one. 
For instance if someone pastes a link in the search bar

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0

I would like there to be a little widget that can play this video embedded in the app.

I tried using the "embed" option from the share tab in you tube and load the video as so:

```
NSString *htmlStr = [self htmlString];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];

-(NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSString *htmlString = @"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"320\" height=\"180\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/hprsNbFPhr0\" \
    allowfullscreen frameborder=\"0\">\
    </iframe>";
    return htmlString;
}
```

but the video is playing in full screen and not in the widget and the widget looks out of proportion